# Looking for help in understanding Jitsuro Nagura's analysis of the upper bound for $\psi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, gamma-function, chebyshev-function

I'm working on understanding [Nagura's analysis](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-28/issue-4/On-the-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number/10.3792/pja/1195570997.full) of the upper bound for $\psi(x)$ which is done in Lemma 2.  I am unclear on one step of his reasoning.

With Lemma 1, he establishes for $x \ge 2000$:

$$\log\Gamma(\lfloor{x}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor+1)- \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{7}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{43}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{1806}}\rfloor+1) < 1.0851x$$

With Lemma 2, he shows that for $x > 0$:

$$\log\Gamma(\lfloor{x}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor+1)- \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{7}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{43}}\rfloor+1) - \log\Gamma(\lfloor{\frac{x}{1806}}\rfloor+1)  \ge \psi(x) -\psi(\frac{x}{1806})$$

Now, it's the next step that confuses me. Based on these two steps, Nagura makes the following argument:

$$\psi(x) < 1.0851(x + \frac{x}{1806} + \frac{x}{1806^2} + \frac{x}{1806^3} + \ldots ) < 1.086x$$

I am having trouble understanding this step.

Does it follow since he has established this step:

$$\psi(x) < 1.0851x + \psi(\frac{x}{1806})$$

And is trying to generalize to a statement of the form:

$$\psi(x) < Kx$$

Thanks,

-Larry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A second application of the inequality
$$\psi(x) <1.0851x+\psi\left(\frac{x}{1806}\right)$$
gives
$$\psi(x) < 1.0851x\left(1+\frac{1}{1806}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{x}{1806^2}\right)$$
In general, induction gives
$$\psi(x) < 1.0851x \left(1+\frac{1}{1806} + \frac{1}{1806^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{1806^k}\right)+\psi \left( \frac{x}{1806^{k+1}}\right).$$
For $k$ sufficiently large, we have $1806^{k+1} > x$, at which point the $\psi$-term is $0$, which gives the bound
$$\psi(x) < 1.0851x\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1806^j}.$$

*Historical note:* this technique was first used by Chebyshev, who showed
$$0.9212x< \psi(x) < 1.1056x$$
for large $x$ to prove Bertrand's postulate (as well as give the correct growth order of $\pi(x)$).  Nagura uses a different approximation function of $\log \mathrm{lcm}(1,\ldots,n)$, and thus achieves different constants.  I wrote an article that includes general constructions of this form, as well as historical notes; it can be found [here](http://integermiscellany.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/notes-on-the-chebyshev-theorem/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the link to the article.  This is exactly the information that I was looking for.  Cheers.  :-)